Catching errors within an R Shiny downloadHandler
When an error occurs within a downloadHandler object, the app will still pop up a download window. Generally the only indication that an error has occurred is that the default filename and type are not right in the pop-up. In this example:
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- mtcars
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      stop()
      write.csv(data, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The stop() here simulates an error. When running the script, the only indication that the widget did not work correctly is that the default filename is downloadData.htm instead of data-[date]-.csv.
Is there a way to catch this error and prevent the download window from launching?
